Euler characteristic number of a circle
$S^1$ is homeomorphic to a square, and is homeomorphic to a polyhedron made of three edges of a triangle (say $3t$).
$\chi(\text{square}) = 4 - 4 + 1 = 1$
$\chi(3 t) = 3 - 3 = 0$
So we obtain different results.
But from Poincaré-Alexander, both results should be the same. What am i doing wrong?

Can you explain where the $+1$ came from in your formula for $\chi($square$)$? I suspect that you are counting the interior of the square, in which case you are not being careful to distinguish between the boundary and the interior of an object in the plane.

@LeeMosher Yes, that is right. Isn't the interior of a square a face? I mean, the interior of a triangle is a face

Rollback if you want.   But $S_1$ seems to be the wrong symbolism.

Then you just need to correct your first sentence, and use consistent language when referring to a square and a triangle, e.g. $S^1$ is homeomorphic to a polyhedron made of the fours edges of a square, and is homeomorphic to a polyhedron made of the three edges of a triangle.

@LeeMosher Oh, now i see. Thank you

I'll turn my comment into an answer.

You just need to use consistent language when referring to a square and a triangle, for example

$S^1$ is homeomorphic to a polyhedron made of the four edges of a square, and is homeomorphic to a polyhedron made of the three edges of a triangle.

One way you can ensure consistency on these kinds of things is to teach yourself to be very careful and very explicit about the mathematical definitions of geometric objects, for example:

The square is the subset
$$[0,1] \times [0,1] \subset \mathbb R^2
$$
The union of the four edges of the square is the subset
$$\bigl([0,1] \times \{0\}\bigr) \cup \bigl(\{1\} \times [0,1]\bigr) \cup \bigl([0,1] \times \{1\}\bigr) \cup \bigl(\{0\} \times [0,1]\bigr) \subset \mathbb R^2
$$

